# Automatically remove unused parameters from constructor (Eclipse, Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, unused-variables

I have a bunch of classes which contain constructors with unused parameters. For example this one:

```
class Book {

    String author;
    String title;

    public Book(String author, String title, int numberOfPages) {       
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Does Eclipse offer any way of automatically removing these unused parameters over multiple files? Removing them manually would take hours.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such mechanism. If you weren't using them, why did you add them?

Comment: I've never run into a feature in Eclipse that performs code review on constructors which you presumably wrote. How did those "unused constructors" get in there in the first place?

Comment: I have a hierarchy of classes. Each class takes a GameSession object as a constructor parameter that it passes up to the top-most class which stores a GameSession variable. I just realized that I do not need to store a GameSession variable, so I removed it from the top-most class. Now I am stuck with all my classes taking in a GameSession object as a class parameter, but they no longer need to pass it to their superclass. super(gameSession); is now super(); but the gameSession construction parameter remains.

Comment: You can use the "Change Method Signature" refactoring to remove the parameter; that will change all the code that calls to constructor as well (including from subclasses, but if the subclasses also had that parameter, you need to remove them individually from subclass constructor signatures as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Eclipse Juno, you can set the compiler to show a warning/error when there's an unused parameter.

1. Open `Window` -> `Preferences`
2. Navigate to `Java` -> `Compiler` -> `Errors/Warnings`
3. Find the node called `Unnecessary code`
4. Set the `Value of parameter is not used` to `Warning` or (better) `Error`.

[image]

This way the compiler will show a warning or will even fail to compile if there are unused method/constructor parameters.

In this case, when you navigate to the `Problems` view, you can apply a `Quick Fix` with a mouse right-click.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Windows->Preference->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings`

In that Unnecessary Code tab. Make `Value of Parameter is not used` as `Error` from `Ignore` or `Warning`.